# Layers with soil properties in the UK

Tags: data-request, geospatial, agriculture

I am looking for companies/sources that can provide GIS layers about soil properties (e.g. soil moisture, soil pH, texture, nutrients) at a relatively high resolution (< 500 m pixel) in the UK for research in the Agritech sector. These sources can be either free or paid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to start by looking at the [UK Soil Observatory](http://www.ukso.org/) run by the [British Geological Survey](https://www.bgs.ac.uk/). There is also the [National Soil Map](http://www.landis.org.uk/data/natmap.cfm) and other datasets in the Cranfeld University [Land Information System](http://www.landis.org.uk/). Both these sources provide online data but may also be able to help you further if you contact them directly.